# Import image from './image.jpeg' results Failed to load module script The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type of "image/jpegerror

Tags: javascript, html

I was trying to import image using:

```
import image from 'image.jpeg';
```

the following error pops out.

> Failed to load module script: The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type of "image/jpeg". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.

in my `index.html`, I imported my main script file as:

```
<script src="index.js" type="module"></script>
```

then in the `index.js`:

```
import image from 'image.jpeg';
```

When I run it using Chrome, it results in the above-mentioned error. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript running in a web browser can *only* import JavaScript modules and (thanks to the new [import assertions](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-import-assertions) feature), with [limited browser support](https://caniuse.com/mdn-javascript_statements_import_import_assertions), JSON.

There are tools (such as WebPack) which can import images, but you aren't using one of them.